# WebGL vs PyOpenGL

Tags: webgl, pyopengl

I'm now assigned to try to integrate some 3d rendering that was done in WebGl to PyOpenGL. I have some samples of both but right from the start I've run into somewhat of a dilemma. For one of the objects that has a huge number of vertexes the WebGL version runs much better than the PyOpenGL one.I'm mostly curious if this is normal or is it some implementation issue.

regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PyOpenGL implementation using VBOs for rendering the geometry?

The main performance issues we ran into when implementing WebGL were JS->C++ call overhead, type conversions and GC runs. Which is why WebGL is using Typed Arrays for data and VBOs for rendering: Typed Arrays reduce the need for type conversions and are potentially faster to GC than JS arrays, whereas VBOs minimize the amount of API calls and CPU->GPU-traffic.

On PyOpenGL I'd imagine the main issue to be type conversions. But you shouldn't run into that with VBOs, hence the question.

Comment: It is using VBO's however PyOpenGL is in it's 3.0 stage and still has some buggy behaviours. Got it working at a slightly better FPS eventually.